# how to list AWS S3 bucket on Joomla/wordpress website?

Tags: wordpress, amazon-s3, joomla2.5

I want to list the contents of my "AWS S3" bucket in a Joomla or WordPress website how can I do that?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Do this first: https://aws.amazon.com/code/Amazon-S3/1713
Then you can embed that HTML into any page of any CMS.